# Emulate UMTS instead of 2G on Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I am currently develop an application that behaves differently on GSM and UTMS networks. However, the emulator can seemingly only "pretend" to be on a GSM network. Is there a way to have it emulate an UMTS connection instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to test the application on actual device... In the emulator you can change the mobile network in the settings but it wont do much if the application strongly depends on the speed difference GSM/2G/EDGE/3G/ or type because the emulator can't emulate it.

Comment: The application doesnt care about the speed, but it behaves differently, so thats what I just want to test it.

Comment: with the emulator you can't emulate it but with just any android device you can change it in the settings -> wireless and network -> mobile networks-> network mode ( the names maybe are different on other devices but generally this is where you can do it)

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of how to do it on an actual device. Hence my question on how to do it on the emulator. It seems like its configured to emulate GSM networks somewhat as GSM specific object types such as CellSignalStrengthGsm behave as expected. However, again, I need to be able to test UMTS and even LTE specific stuff, so it would be nice to have the emulator help me out